# Converter svg para png em PHP

Tags: php, html, svg

Estive pesquisando e testando implementações alocadas em repositórios, contudo não consegui aplicar ao meu caso. Gostaria de saber há alguma forma nativa de fazer isso, considerando que o arquivo svg está armazenado em uma pasta de meu servidor. Tentei utilizar o Imagick da seguinte forma:

```
    <?php
    $im = new Imagick();
    try {
      $im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel("transparent"));
       $svg = '<svg aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="address-book" class="svg-inline--fa fa-address-book fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M436 160c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12v-40c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-20V48c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48H48C21.5 0 0 21.5 0 48v416c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h320c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-48h20c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12v-40c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-20v-64h20c6.6 0 12-5.4 12-12v-40c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-20v-64h20zm-228-32c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64s-28.7 64-64 64-64-28.7-64-64 28.7-64 64-64zm112 236.8c0 10.6-10 19.2-22.4 19.2H118.4C106 384 96 375.4 96 364.8v-19.2c0-31.8 30.1-57.6 67.2-57.6h5c12.3 5.1 25.7 8 39.8 8s27.6-2.9 39.8-8h5c37.1 0 67.2 25.8 67.2 57.6v19.2z"></path></svg>';
      $im->readImageBlob($svg);
      $im->setImageFormat("png24");
      header("Content-Type: image/png");
      echo $im;
      $im->writeImage('convert.png');
    }
    catch (ImagickException $e) {
      echo $e;
    }
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
?>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a identificar o erro nessa situação?

Comment: Já tentou usar o [Imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/imagick.examples-1.php)?  Ele é uma extensão que usa o [Image Magick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php)

Comment: Eu estive testando alguns exemplos de repositórios que usa esse Imagick, mas não obtive sucesso.

?>`

Comment: Você executou esse código que você postou? Se sim, printou algum erro?

Comment: Executei direto do servidor e não retorna nada.